# Is it possible to have a dictionary of dictionary of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like a three-dimensional hash in python - a dictionary of a dictionary of a dictionary. I don't know if this is possible and I'm having some problems I don't understand that makes me suspect it isn't possible.  An example piece of code is below that reads two comma separated files ('tv.txt' and 'film.txt') and puts the data on a dictionary of dictionary of dictionary (dOfDofD).  The two files look like this:

**tv.txt**

```
Muppets,female,Miss Piggy
Muppets,male,Kermit
Simpsons,female,Marge 
Simpsons,male,Homer
```

**film.txt**

```
Gone with the Wind,female,Vivien Leigh
Gone with the Wind,male,Clark Gable 
Anthony and Cleopatra,female,Elizabeth Taylor 
Anthony and Cleopatra,male,Richard Burton
```

My code reads these two files and creates the dOfDofD, but when it comes to retrieve the data, it seems some of it is missing in a systematic way: only the last example of the final level of dictionary appears to exist.  The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string

dOfDofD = {}

mediaList = ['tv', 'film']

showSet = set()

for media in mediaList:
    fName = media + ".txt"
    f = open(fName, 'r')
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        dataList = string.splitfields(line, ',')
        show = dataList[0]
        showSet.add(show)
        gender = dataList[1]
        name = dataList[2]
        dOfDofD[show] = {}
        dOfDofD[show][media] = {}
        dOfDofD[show][media][gender] = name
    f.close()

for show in showSet:
    for media in dOfDofD[show]:
        for gender in dOfDofD[show][media]:
            print "show: %s. media: %s. gender: %s. character: %s." % \
                    (show, media, gender, dOfDofD[show][media][gender])
```

This only prints out the male characters, as if the female ones have been overwritten (which were set up first).

```
show: Simpsons. media: tv. gender: male. character: Homer. 
show: Gone with the Wind. media: film. gender: male. character: Clark Gable.
show: Muppets. media: tv. gender: male. character: Kermit. 
show: Anthony and Cleopatra. media: film. gender: male. character: Richard Burton.
```

I'm running python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: yes it's definitely possible... the problem is you are re-initialising the `dOfDofD[show]` dictionary each time through the `for line in f` loop

Comment: `{'is': {'it': {'possible': 'yes'}}}`

Comment: I would use the name as the first key since it will always be unique and won't be overwritten

Comment: Dictionary *values* can be literally anything: if you can do `my_var = somevalue` you can do `my_dict[somekey] = somevalue` - meaning that yes, it can be another ductionary (or even *the same* dictionary if you really want). The keys do have some restrictions however, and `my_dict[another_dict] = 5` is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes: creating nested dictionaries is possible.

you keep overwriting `dOfDofD[show]` for every line in your text file.

you could try this:

```
if show in dOfDofD:
    show_dict = dOfDofD[show]
else:
    show_dict = {}
    dOfDofD[show] = show_dict
# do something with show_dict
```

and something similar for `dOfDofD[show][media]`.

or you could use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

and seeing that your input file is comma-separated: have a look at the [python `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html).

Comment: In the words of one my example characters: "D'oh!".  Thanks very much for spotting this and suggesting a solution - I've inserted an 'if' loop.

Answer (score 0):

Following from [hiro protagonist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4954037/hiro-protagonist)'s post, here's the snipet of code I used:

```
for media in mediaList:
    fName = media + ".txt"
    f = open(fName, 'r')
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        dataList = string.splitfields(line, ',')
        show = dataList[0]
        showSet.add(show)
        gender = dataList[1]
        name = dataList[2]
        if show in dOfDofD:
            if media in dOfDofD[show]:
                dOfDofD[show][media][gender] = name
            else:
                dOfDofD[show][media] = {}
                dOfDofD[show][media][gender] = name
        else:
            dOfDofD[show] = {}
            dOfDofD[show][media] = {}
            dOfDofD[show][media][gender] = name
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each time you are adding a new pair to the dictionary, you're creating new dicts for `dOfDofD[show]` and `dOfDofD[show][media]`. To fix this, you could use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault). Here's the line: `dOfDOfD.setdefault(show, {}).setdefault(media, {})[gender] = name`.

```
dOfDOfD = {}

mediaList = ['tv', 'film']

showSet = set()

for media in mediaList:
    with open('{}.txt'.format(media), 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            show, gender, name = line.split(',')
            showSet.add(show)
            dOfDOfD.setdefault(show, {}).setdefault(media, {})[gender] = name

for show in showSet:
    for media in dOfDOfD[show]:
        for gender in dOfDOfD[show][media]:
            print "show: {}. media: {}. gender: {}. character: {}.".format(
                show, media, gender, dOfDOfD[show][media][gender])
```

> show: Simpsons. media: tv. gender: male. character: Homer.
>
> show: Simpsons. media: tv. gender: female. character: Marge.
>
> show: Gone with the Wind. media: film. gender: male. character: Clark Gable.
>
> show: Gone with the Wind. media: film. gender: female. character: Vivien Leigh.
>
> show: Muppets. media: tv. gender: male. character: Kermit.
>
> show: Muppets. media: tv. gender: female. character: Miss Piggy.
>
> show: Anthony and Cleopatra. media: film. gender: male. character: Richard Burton.
>
> show: Anthony and Cleopatra. media: film. gender: female. character: Elizabeth Taylor.

In addition, I changed some other things in your program. I renamed `dOfDofD` to `dOfDOfD` (proper camel casing). I used a `with...as` statement to open the files, which provides numerous advantages (I will not go into them here, but if you're curious just Google it). And I changed your string formatting with `%s' to use the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method (the now recommended way of formatting a string).